# Not able to copy the file to another bucket showing error(NoSuchKey: The specified key does not exist.)

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3

There is space in my key(test 12/3/2017.csv) but for without space is key working properly. I am using aws javascript sdk.

```
var params = {
        Bucket: bucketname, 
        CopySource: `/bucketname/test 12/3/2017.csv`, 
        Key: `test 12/3/2017.csv`
    };

s3bucket.copyObject(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err){
                console.log(err, err.stack); 
                debugger
            } else {
                console.log(data); 
                debugger
            }             
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the key needs to be URL encoded.

As can be seen in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50831566/copy-file-from-one-aws-s3-bucket-to-another-bucket-with-node/50832183) question, there are several options to work around it if you do have a space in your key.

An option that worked for the OP in this question was to use `encodeURIComponent(file.name)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the space with a + sign.
E.g.

```
CopySource: `/bucketname/test+12/3/2017.csv`
```

If that doesn't work, try replacing the space with either '%20' or '%2B'.